# Notations not clear related to set theory

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have the following notations that I don't understand what it stands for? A is a group [image]
what is that weird looking $p$ does it mean the all of the subsets of A in pairs like $(a_1,a_2)$ while $a_1\in A$ and $a_2 \in A$ what is the different of that and [image] this $p$ is different does it mean all of the subset of group $\mathbb N$

I'd be really glad if someone could clear this, I'm confused.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For a set $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denote the power set of $A$ which is a set containing all the subsets of $A$. For example if $A=\{1,2\}$, then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

Comment: @AlanWang I have learned about power set, yet I still do not understand why the $p$ is different if both are power sets

Comment: Do you mean the $P(\Bbb{N})$ that you have stated? May I know where you get this symbol $P$?

Comment: I copied a picture from homework I got to do, I just don't understand the differents between them.

Comment: I think you should at least post the entire question so that we can determine whether $P$ is indeed $\mathcal{P}$ or it has other meaning that is not power set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol

$\mathcal P$

stands for the *power set*, i.e. $$\mathcal P(X)$$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ (also sometimes written as $2^X$).

The symbol $\times$ denotes the cartesian product, i.e. $$X\times Y = \{(x,y)| x\in X, y\in Y\}$$ is the set of all pairs of elements from $x$ and $y$.

---

So, $$\mathcal P(A\times A)$$ is the set of all subsets of pairs of elements of $A$. For example, if $A=\{1,2\}$, then $A\times A = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$
and $$\mathcal P(A\times A) = \\
\{\{\}, \{(1,1)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(2,1)\},\{(2,2)\},\\
\{(1,1),(1,2)\}, \{(1,1),(2,1)\}, \{(1,1),(2,2)\}, \{(1,2),(2,1)\}, \{(1,2),(2,2)\}, \{(2,1),(2,2)\}, \\
\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}, \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}, \{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}, \{(1,2),(2,1), (2,2)\},\\
\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\} \}$$

Comment: But why in the second picture it written as $p$ instand of the symbol of power set?

Comment: @JaVaPG Could be a typo, could be some strange notation. How can anyone know that? You could at least provide a picture...

Comment: this is a picture from homework.

Comment: @JaVaPG Usually, $\mathcal P$ denotes the power set. That's all I can tell you. I can't read the mind of the person who gave you homework...